# Is there a way to bookmark all tabs in Chrome?

Tags: chrome-for-android, bookmarks

Is there a way to bookmark all tabs in Chrome for Android? (i.e. right click and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> functions are not available)

If it helps, I'm using Android *tablet*.

Comment: This is not a direct answer, is an idea. I mean, just like Chrome reads a file with all open tabs list, for syncing or so, it must be possible to make a script or a little program, like a micro app, that reads and copies those URLs.

Comment: There is [a chromium issue going on for years requesting a "bookmark all" feature for Android](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1026222); it has been closed at least once (that I know of) but has been re-opened because of demand - please consider endorsing it.

Answer (score 19):

I came across this question while looking for a way to do this as well, and it appears that Chrome for Android does not currently have this option.

The following proved useful to me as a workaround:

- Open Chrome on your desktop (logged into the same account as on your
  tablet).
- In a new window, either hit (Ctrl + H) or go to 'Settings > History &
  recent tabs > History'.
- From there, it should show your History/Tabs sorted by device.
- Next to the name of your tablet, there should be a small box with a
  arrow pointing down. Clicking on this will give you the options to
  either 'Collapse List' or 'Open All'.
- Select 'Open All', and all of your tabs from your tablet should open.
- Now you can either hit (Ctrl+Shift+D), or right-click on one of the
  tabs and select 'Bookmark all tabs...'.
- Select a folder for your bookmarks, and you should be set.

Granted, a bit more leg-work than simply hitting a button, but it is the only real option I've found for when you have 100+ tabs on your tablet that need bookmarking.

Comment: This sync to desktop is not very reliable actually. I have around 100 tabs open on Chrome in Android, and on the desktop it's only showing me around half of them. Now that I bookmarked these, it's not showing me any tabs on the desktop anymore (or only 1-2), even though I still have >50 open on my mobile. This was a few weeks ago, so waiting, phone reboot, etc., all doesn't fix it.

Comment: This method doesn't show the opened tabs, it shows the history... It's not the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some day Google Chrome for Android will support extensions, for now [Yandex Browser for Android](https://browser.yandex.ru) support [Extensions](https://addons.opera.com/en/search/?query=copy+url) from Opera.
Yandex Browser and Opera both based on [Blink web engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(web_engine)), same as Google Chrome.