# How can I conveniently save the urls of the opened webpages in https://www.google.com/bookmarks/?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I have opened a number of web pages in  Google Chrome browser in  my android phone. Is it possible to conveniently save the urls of the opened webpages in https://www.google.com/bookmarks/?

This is especially helpful on android phone, since google chrome browser there doesn't provide bookmarking all open webpages into the browser at once.

Thanks.

Comment: That is meant for bookmarks (link) and you want to save open url pages there?

Comment: I want to save it into the browser, and access it from my laptop by synchronization between browsers on my android and my laptop. But I don't find a way to bookmark all open pages in chrome browser on android. So  I am looking for a workaround, and wondering whether it is possible to bookmark all open pages into https://www.google.com/bookmarks/

Comment: It looks like you missed existing question on that :) If solutions doesn't work edit your question to mention that to retract close flag

Comment: Thanks. I found https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112448/is-there-a-way-to-bookmark-all-tabs-in-chrome, so concluded it was not possible to bookmark all open webpages in chrome. Can any reply in the link you gave solve the problem which no reply in the link I gave can?

Comment: IDK didn't try either not having the need